# C++ boost locale + lexical cast throws an exception

Tags: c++, boost

```
boost::locale::generator gen;   
std::locale loc = gen("de_DE.UTF-8");
std::locale::global(loc);

std::string s = "3,14";
double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>(s);
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

Why does this code throw an exception? Boost Locale does not affect lexical cast?

I want to use a comma as a separator, not a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost Locale doesn't apply to any number. You have to tell it using IO manipulators. E.g.:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71973efa79f64aa3)**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace as = boost::locale::as;

int main() {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    auto de = gen("de_DE.utf8");
    // std::locale::global(de);

    std::cout.imbue(de);
    std::cin.imbue(de);

    std::cout << 134.45 << std::endl;
    std::cout << as::number << 134.45 << std::endl;
    std::cout << as::currency << 134.45 << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
134.45
134,45
134,45 €
```

So, it stands to reason that the following will work:  [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ea370347a79720)

```
if (double punkt; is("123.45") >> punkt)
     std::cout << "Punkt " << punkt << "\n";
else std::cout << "Punkt failed\n";

if (double komma; is("123,45") >> komma)
     std::cout << "Komma " << komma << " (OOPS!)\n";
else std::cout << "Komma failed\n";

if (double nummer; is("123,45") >> as::number >> nummer)
     std::cout << "Nummer " << nummer << "\n";
else std::cout << "Nummer failed\n";
```

Prints (note the `OOPS` case):

```
Punkt 123,45 €
Komma 123,00 € (OOPS!)
Nummer 123,45 €
```

### Making It Work?

Even if you do set the global locale, `lexical_cast` will not accept the manipulators. But [Boost Convert](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/convert/doc/html/index.html) does:

> *The original hope was to see boost::lexical_cast extended to be applicable to a wider range of deployment scenarios. However, after discussions with Kevlin Henney (the boost::lexical_cast author) and in the Boost Developers forum it was collectively decided that the desired extensions were not compatible with the original design and the idea of what boost::lexical_cast embodied and, therefore, a new component with richer interface and functionality was needed. That decision resulted in the development of Boost.Convert described in this document.*

The 30s introduction I'd give: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06b41e28330e731d)**

```
#include <boost/convert.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace cnv = boost::cnv;

int main() {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale::global(gen("de_DE.utf8"));

    cnv::cstream cnv;
    cnv(boost::locale::as::number);
    auto from_string = cnv::apply<double>(std::ref(cnv));
    auto to_string   = cnv::apply<std::string>(std::ref(cnv));

    std::cout << "Parsed "    << from_string("123,45") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Formatted " << to_string(123.45)     << "\n";
}
```

### But, Lexical Cast!

Of course, it is quite convenient to have lexical_cast Just Work(TM). You might introduce a light-weight wrapper type:

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4313e8d1d8830873)**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace as = boost::locale::as;

struct Number {
    double value_;
    Number(double init = {}) : value_(init) {}
    operator double() const { return value_; }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Number& num) {
        return is >> as::number >> num.value_ >> as::posix;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Number const& num) {
        return os << as::number << num.value_ << as::posix;
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale::global(gen("de_DE.utf8"));

    std::cout << "Formatted: " << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(Number{234.56}) << "\n";
    double parsed = boost::lexical_cast<Number>("345,67");
    std::cout << "Parsed: " << parsed << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Formatted: 234,56
Parsed: 345.67
```

Note that you might even evolve `Number` to be a vocabulary type, so you won't have to wrap it for conversions.